# Opening just white web page with Edge Webdriver - Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

i am trying to set Selenium for Edge and doesnt work:( Opening page is just white.

I am using Edge 120.0.2210.160 (64), driver the same.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('https://bing.com')
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

And i get this:

```
[21620:20396:0205/134806.901:ERROR:policy_logger.cc(156)] :components\enterprise\browser\controller\chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(161) Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled. Please use the `--enable-chrome-browser-cloud-management` command line flag to enable it if you are not using the official Google Chrome build.
[21620:20396:0205/134806.972:ERROR:chrome_content_browser_client.cc(1285)] NewTabPageLocation policy is supplying invalid URL: about://blank
[21620:20396:0205/134806.974:ERROR:chrome_content_browser_client.cc(1285)] NewTabPageLocation policy is supplying invalid URL: about://blank
[21620:20396:0205/134806.975:ERROR:chrome_content_browser_client.cc(1285)] NewTabPageLocation policy is supplying invalid URL: about://blank
[21620:20396:0205/134806.975:ERROR:chrome_content_browser_client.cc(1285)] NewTabPageLocation policy is supplying invalid URL: about://blank
[21620:20396:0205/134806.976:ERROR:chrome_content_browser_client.cc(1285)] NewTabPageLocation policy is supplying invalid URL: about://blank

DevTools remote debugging is disallowed by the system admin.
[21620:20396:0205/134807.178:ERROR:edge_auth_errors.cc(514)] EDGE_IDENTITY: Get Default OS Account failed: Error: Primary Error: kImplicitSignInFailure, Secondary Error: kAccountProviderFetchError, Platform error: 0, Error string:

[21620:20396:0205/134809.397:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(141)] Failed to read length for configuration 1.
[21620:20396:0205/134809.397:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(141)] Failed to read length for configuration 2.
[21620:20396:0205/134809.398:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(100)] Failed to read all configuration descriptors. Expected 3, got 1.
[21620:20396:0205/134809.400:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(192)] [13:48:09.400] USB: usb_device_win.cc:95 Failed to read descriptors from \\?\usb#vid_03f0&pid_a31d#0123456789abcdef#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\goryainovaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Testovani\edge2.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver.get('https://bing.com')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
  File "C:\Users\goryainovaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\goryainovaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\goryainovaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 208, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\goryainovaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\goryainovaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\goryainovaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF703040362+58194]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF702FCECC2+216514]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF702DE9E1B]
 
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::to_string [0x00007FF7031F6D0A+1051354]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF702EAF596]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::clear [0x00007FF702F46215+34245]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF702FD89A8+256680]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFD35177344+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFD354426B1+33]
```

I search all web, but couldnt find solution :(
PS. i deleted repeating messages to be able to publish here

Comment: What version of selenium do you use?

Comment: Do you put the `msedgedriver` executable folder to your `PATH` environment variable? The latest version of Edge is 121.0.2277.106, you could update Edge and Edge WebDriver to the latest version and test again. Besides, please kill all existing Edge processes in Task Manager before running the code, to see if this can fix the issue.

Comment: @Shawn i am using selenium 4

Comment: @YuZhou i have in path, as well now downloaded latest version of Edge and Webdriver, and kill all processes, Didnt work unfortunatly :(

Comment: Do you launch Edge with SYSTEM account? If so, the issue is expected. If not, could you please try [this workaround](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4403#c35) to see if it wokrs: `edge_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-pipe')`?